# How i can use looping to declare dynamic variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic

i have a lot of variables in JavaScript maybe 50 variables,
and i want to declare variables by using loop,
how i can do it dynamically.

```js
var img1,img2,img3;
for(var i =1; i<50; i++){
  var img+i = document.getElementById(i);
  /* i wanna doing some thing like that */
}
```

Comment: is it ok to put them in an object or array? `obj["img" + i] = document.getElementById(i);`

Comment: What you're looking for is called an "array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create variables `img1` ... `img49` on the global object (in the global namespace):

```
for(var i = 1; i < 50; i++){
  window['img'+i] = document.getElementById(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider storing variables in an object:

```
var images = {}

for (var i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
  images['img' + i] = document.getElementById(i)
}

// usage
console.log(images.img5)
```

Or in an array:

```
var images = []

for (var i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
  images.push(document.getElementById(i))
}

// usage   
console.log(images[4])
```

Comment: Actually i do it,
but i don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a javascript array.
e.g--

```
var array=[];
for(var i =1; i<50; i++){
    array[i] = document.getElementById(i);
}
```

after that you can call that element by array[i]